# Creditcard store first six digits PCI reference

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card

I need to store masked PAN with first six digits and last four digits along with the card expiry month and year. Is it safe to do it according to the PCI rules?

Regarding four digits has been previously discussed in the following post.

[Minimum Requirements For Storing Last Four Digits](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19860/minimum-requrements-for-storing-last-4-digits-of-credit-card-number)

It mentions that storing first six digits and last four digits is ok with PCI compliance. Is there a official PCI documentation with this information?

I referred to [pci_dss_v2](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf) and [pci_fs_data_storage](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf), but could not find an answer.

> 3.3 Mask PAN when displayed (the first 
>   six and last four digits are the maximum
>   number of digits to be displayed).

The rule most are referring is the 3.3 requirement. But this only applies if I am *displaying* the PAN, but it does not mention anything about *storing* first six + mask + last 4 digits.
Appreciate any help...

Comment: Note, not that it affects your question, however the latest version of the PCI DSS standard is [3.1](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1.pdf), not v2.

Comment: From your comments it sounds like you're asking the wrong question. Imho you should be asking how you can reduce your PCI scope or even who is responsible for PCI compliance (given you seem to be doing this work for a client). Pragmatically if what you're concerned with is styling there are other options, check out an iframe service like the one offered by Braintree (if you have a choice of payment processor) or Spreedly (for a wide but potentially expensive choice). Using those services you might get away with SAQ A, which is better for everyone really.

Comment: Hi Richard, in my case I don't have options to select a payment gateway as it's been already selected. I tried the Iframe option (created a fully functional prototype as well), but the UI modifications are limited and my client wants to have complete control over UI changes. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your questions indicate you are already processing card holder data, either by transfering PANs or storing (partial) PANs, you fall in the category of SAQ-D. So this means you should be already undergoing PCI audits (provided you have over 300k transactions annually), so best is to check with your QSA and see what they say.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "processing", is it relating the masking the data and store? Can you give me a reference to this?. Would it be ok if I just store last 4 digits and expiry, will it also go under the same rule.

Comment: @Dhanuka777 the moment you accept a card number and it is sent to your machines, it's considered processing, even if you do not store it and just pass it onto another service provider like  a payment gateway, it's still considered processing as it resides at some point in your volatile memory.

Comment: Lucas, one more thing "...you should be already undergoing PCI audits". My app is still in development stage. Do I have to get this audited by someone since I am "processing" credit card?

Comment: Yes, after your development, before you start accepting real cards, you are required to get your full solution and network environment audited by a QSA. This is far from cheap. If this is just a small part of your application, it might be better to integrate a third party payment gateway that avoids you touching the card.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, this is very helpful. I am using Authorize.Net, even if I do not store card details, do I have to go through the audit for SAQ-D?

Comment: Unless the payment is done entirely by the payment gateway and your servers never receive the credit card details, yes you have to. There are other solutions that offer you means of payment through credit card that work with callbacks to notify you of succesful payment without the credit card number to be known by your environment.

Comment: I am aware about those options, but the issue is that those third party UIs provide minimal UI changes and they don't match with the modern UIs. So my client wants to accept Cards with the website, which comes with more cost at the end of the day. Thanks Lucas.

Comment: Yes, just be aware that a pci audit can run into several thousands of dollars and not only requires your website to be secure but also puts requirements on your network design

Comment: Why do you have to do an audit? That's only if you're want level 1 compliance, which is for those processing more than 300k transactions a year (for SAQ D service provider anyway).

Comment: @Richard you're right, let me clarify that in my answer

Answer (score 2):

The first 6 digits are not extremely sensitive information. They comprise the IIN or Issuer Identification Number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number). The last four digits are also not considered sensitive information. In fact the first six and last four are the maximum number of digits that are allowed to be displayed (see PCI DSS 3.3 https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf All other PCI number references come from this document).

However the EXP Date + PAN IS considered sensitive information. Page 2 of this document has a nice explanation of storage procedures (https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf).

In addition 3.4 applies in this case. You have rendered the number unusable through truncation (although the Luhn Checksum allows for the number to be guessable). However you must protect the EXP Date and it is recommended (note that it does not appear to be required) to not store the truncated PAN in plan text but to stack protection with one way hashing or encryption.

Comment: In my case I am not storing PAN. "EXP Date + PAN" is not going to be stored. It's the first six digits + last four digits (not all digits) with expiry. Isn't that safe to do it?

Comment: In the page 2 (fs_data_storage), it says, " Be sure to mask PAN whenever
it is displayed. The first six and last four digits are the maximum number of digits that may be displayed.". What if you only store the masked number, is that allowed?

Comment: @Dhanuka777 That would be "Truncation" under 3.4, however you must protect the EXP Date see my second link.

Answer (score 2):

I you mixed the meaning of the different requirements and have a certain confusion.

**Requirements 3.3** "Mask PAN when displayed (the first six and last four digits are the maximum number of digits to be displayed)."
talks about **display not storage !** 
if you mask the PAN it provides a solution for this requirement.

**Requirements 3.4** 3.4 Render PAN unreadable anywhere it is stored ..." talks about **storage not display !**

You wrote "I need to store masked PAN" masked PAN is related with Requirement 3.3. and storage is related with requirement 3.4 to fulfill this requirement you can use one way hash / truncation / cryptography / token